# Calculate percentage difference between two rows

Tags: postgresql

I have this query that produced the table below.

```
select season,
       guildname,
       count(guildname) as mp_count, 
       (count(guildname)/600::float)*100 as grank
from mp_rankings
group by season, guildname
order by grank desc
```

| season | guildname | mp_count | grank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | LEGENDS | 56 | 9.33333333333333 |
| 9 | LEGENDS | 54 | 9 |
| 10 | EVERGLADE | 50 | 8.33333333333333 |
| 9 | Mystic | 46 | 7.66666666666667 |
| 10 | Mystic | 42 | 7 |
| 9 | EVERGLADE | 39 | 6.5 |
| 10 | 100 | 36 | 6 |
| 9 | PARABELLUM | 33 | 5.5 |
| 10 | PARABELLUM | 29 | 4.83333333333333 |
| 9 | 100 | 29 | 4.83333333333333 |

I wanted to create a new column that calculates the percentage difference between the two seasons using identical guildnames. For example:

| season | guildname | mp_count | grank | prev_season_percent_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | LEGENDS | 56 | 9.33333333333333 | 0.33% |
| 10 | EVERGLADE | 50 | 8.33333333333333 | 1.83% |

The resulting table will only show the current season (which is the highest season value, `10` in this case) and adds a new column `prev_season_percent_diff`, which is the current season's `grank` minus the previous season's `grank`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is `prev_season_percent_diff` calculated?

Comment: Did you really mean to code `(count(guildname)/600::float)*100)`? It's the same as `count(*)/6`.

Comment: @Bohemian Hi, just the difference between grank of season 9 and season 10.

Comment: That difference for EVERGLADE is 9.33 - 6.5 which is 2.83, but your sample output has 0.65 - please clarify.

Comment: @Bohemian Hi, I edit the post. Sorry, I was manually typing the second table and didn't realize I entered the wrong value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [*Common Table Expression*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) ("CTE") for the grouped result and join it to itself to calculate the difference to the previous season:

```sql
with summary as (
  select
    season,
    guildname,
    count(*) as mp_count, -- simplified equivalent expression
    count(*)/6 as grank -- simplified equivalent expression
  from mp_rankings
  group by season, guildname
)
select
  a.season,
  a.guildname,
  a.mp_count,
  a.grank,
  a.mp_count - b.mp_count as prev_season_percent_diff
from summary a
left join summary b on b.guildname = a.guildname
  and b.season = a.season - 1
where a.season = (select max(season) from summary)
order by a.grank desc
```

If you actually want a `%` in the result, concatenate a `%` to the difference calculation.